# Regex to find string with only numbers, but match only when preceeded with # or \s and followed by space

Tags: regex

I am attempting to find a regex that will find a string of numbers and only match if they are preceded with white space of a pound sign and followed by either white space or a line break. For example, the following would match:

1. `#1234`
2. `#001234`
3. `000123`
4. `1234`

But the following would not:

1. `123-456`
2. `@1234`
3. `123kok`

Using one of those online regex sandboxes, I tried to use a negative look behind: 
`\d*(?<=#|\s)\d{1,10}`  but I can't get the *following* to work. So out of these:

1. `123-456`
2. `@1234`
3. `123kok`

`456` would match

Comment: Try `(?<![^\s#])\d+(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=...)` is a lookbehind (*preceded by ...*), `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind (*not preceded by ...*). Writting `\d*(?<=#|\s)` doesn't make sense and behaves like `(?<=#|\s)` alone since a same position can't be a digit and a `#` or a whitespace at the same time. But it isn't the problem. All you need is an assertion for the condition **after** the digits: a lookahead (negative here).

```
(?<![^\s#])\d+(?!\S)
```

The double negation: **not** preceded by a character that is **not** a whitespace or a #, is useful to include the start of the string. Same thing for the negative lookahead (not followed by a character that is not a whitespace) to include the end of the string.

Obviously:

```
(?<=^|\s|#)\d+(?=\s|$)
```

is correct too but longer.